# 504 Gateway Time-out error when making cURL request in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I'm encountering a 504 Gateway Time-out error when attempting to make a cURL request in a WordPress environment. I've included the relevant code below:

```
function welkvoxapi() {
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://wv{{wolkvox_server}}.wolkvox.com/api/v2/campaign.php?api=add_record&type_campaign={{type_campaign}}&campaign_id={{campaign_id}}&campaign_status={{campaign_status}}',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'[{
            "customer_name": "namewv",
            "customer_last_name": "field_3d8268c",
            "customer_id": "field_d3976af",
            "city": "field_5dd4679",
            "opt1": "field_9f10881",
            "opt3": "field_6d254ff",
            "opt4": "field_363c904",
            "opt5": "field_a5de87f",
            "opt6": "field_dc05404",
            "opt7": "field_9a9a683",
            "opt8": "field_383d50f",
            "email": "field_8981d35"  


}]',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'wolkvox-token: {{token}}'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


}
add_action('init', 'welkvoxapi');
```

I've added the following cURL code to my WordPress theme's functions.php file to interact with the Wolkvox API. However, when I save the code, the page doesn't load, and I encounter a "504 Gateway Time-out" error.

Wolkvoks [Documentation.](https://www.wolkvox.com/en/apis-v2-2/2-1-inserting-records-in-the-campaign-predictive/)

Additionally, I am hosting my WordPress site on AWS, but I'm unsure if this is relevant to the encountered issue.

I have replaced the corresponding information in both the CURLOPT_URL and the token.

I would appreciate any guidance on resolving the "504 Gateway Time-out" issue. Additionally, if there are any considerations or best practices for integrating cURL requests in WordPress, I'd love to know.

Comment: Try copy-pasting the URL into your browser - you'll likely get an error, but does it come back fast, or does it also time out?  You could try [adding and displaying some curl debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl), to verify WP and the theme are correctly running that method and that the curl code is actually running.

Answer (score -1):

Start with creating a simple PHP file that contains a form, and post that. Something like this:

Pay attention to 2 things:

1. Make sure the action in the form is OK, and contains the same as your example in your question (that long URL).
   So make sure you replace all the placeholders like {wolkvox_server}} with actual right values.
2. Make sure you add a header in your HTTP request with your token.
   'wolkvox-token: {{token}}'

Then mimic the CURL call:

```
<form action="https://wv{{wolkvox_server}}.wolkvox.com/api/v2etcetc" Method="POST">
<input type="text" name="customer_last_name" value="field_3d8268c">
<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="field_d3976af">

etc etc
 <input type="Submit" value="Post me">
</form>
```

Put in all your POST name values pairs:

```
"customer_name": "namewv",
            "customer_last_name": "field_3d8268c",
            "customer_id": "field_d3976af",
            "city": "field_5dd4679",
            "opt1": "field_9f10881",
            "opt3": "field_6d254ff",
            "opt4": "field_363c904",
            "opt5": "field_a5de87f",
            "opt6": "field_dc05404",
            "opt7": "field_9a9a683",
            "opt8": "field_383d50f",
            "email": "field_8981d35"
```

What does it come back with?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question...

Comment: @DarkBee I know. It is the first step to approach te problem. And it doesn't fit into a comment.